# How to Display one Image at a Time from external JSON file - creating Slideshow

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to create a slideshow by using an external JSON array of Images, and I have managed to make the 'next' button to display all the images on click, but I cannot seem to figure out how to make only one different image appear at one time when the button is clicked.

I need help with the following:

1) How to make next button show an image one at a time
2) How to make caption show in similar fashion

```
This is my HTML: 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow.css">

    <title> JSON SlideShow </title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <header>
    <h1> JSON SlideShow </h1>
    </header>
    <br>
    <button id="nextbtn"> Next </button>

    <div id="slideshow"></div>
    <div id="caption"></div>

    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>

This is my Java Script:

    var prevbtn = document.getElementById("prevbtn");
    var nextbtn = document.getElementById("nextbtn");
    var slideContainer = document.getElementById("slideshow");
    nextbtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var JSONarray = new XMLHttpRequest();
    JSONarray.open('GET', 'http://localhost/slide.json');
    JSONarray.onload = function () {
    var mySlides = JSON.parse(JSONarray.responseText);
    createHTML(mySlides);
    };
    JSONarray.send();   
    });

    function createHTML(slide) {
    var i;
    var image = "";

    for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    image += '<img src=" '+ slide[i].image_name + '"></img>';
    }
    slideContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', image);

    }; 


This is my CSS


    /* Slideshow container */
    .slideshowcontainer {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto; 
    }

    /* Hide the images by default */
    #slideshow {
    display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use execute your `XMLHttpRequest` on `DOM` load and then set the first image with `click` events to deal with selecting the images?

Comment: @NewToJS how can I do that?